# Orphans and widows in fo:table to control page break within fo:table-cell

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm faced with a styling problem when using tables with a lot of text within the cells. Sometimes the text is unfortunately separated by the page break. As you can see in the following picture the **paragraph1** from **row3** is divided by the page break.

[image: Unfortunate page-break within the cells of **row3**]

What we need is that **row3 paragraph1 line1** is put to the next page together with the rest of the paragraph.

We tried using attributes like "orphans" and "widows" but those do not seem to have any effect within table cells. We also tried using block with **keep-together** attribute, but paragraphs might be larger than one page so that content gets cut off. The only other thing, we could come up with, is to use **keep-with-next** with fo:blocks which we use on the first few paragraphs of a row. But this looks sloppy, complicated and more like a rule of thumb estimate.

I have put together a "minimal" example that can be tested using http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender/ . I hope you can help me with a solution. Maybe you could also tell me why "orphans" and "widows" does not seem to work here.

Thank you in advance!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <heading>head1</heading>
        <description>
            <p>row1 paragraph1 line1
            row1 paragraph1 line2
            row1 paragraph1 line3
            row1 paragraph1 line4
            row1 paragraph1 line5</p>

            <p>row1 paragraph2 line1
            row1 paragraph2 line2
            row1 paragraph2 line3
            row1 paragraph2 line4</p>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <heading>head1</heading>
        <description>
            <p>row2 paragraph1 line1
            row2 paragraph1 line2
            row2 paragraph1 line3
            row2 paragraph1 line4
            row2 paragraph1 line5</p>

            <p>row2 paragraph2 line1
            row2 paragraph2 line2
            row2 paragraph2 line3
            row2 paragraph2 line4
            row2 paragraph2 line5
            row2 paragraph2 line6
            row2 paragraph2 line7</p>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <heading>head1</heading>
        <description>
            <p>row3 paragraph1 line1
            row3 paragraph1 line2
            row3 paragraph1 line3
            row3 paragraph1 line4
            row3 paragraph1 line5</p>

            <p>row3 paragraph2 line1
            row3 paragraph2 line2
            row3 paragraph2 line3
            row3 paragraph2 line4</p>
        </description>
    </item>
</root>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="//root">
        <fo:root language="DE">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-landscape" page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm" margin-top="5mm" margin-bottom="5mm" margin-left="5mm" margin-right="5mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="25mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="25mm" display-align="before" precedence="true"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-landscape">
                <fo:flow reference-orientation="0" border-collapse="collapse" flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="80%"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="solid">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" orphans="4" widows="4">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//description/p">
        <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT** Added the p-tag to the xml input. I posted the wrong version of xml.

Comment: I'm curious why this question is tagged `xslt` - is it really a question about the transformation process, or only about what XSL-FO to generate?

Comment: I thought maybe there is a possibility in xslt to count characters or something to calculate the page break manually... although this seems even more complicated than anything else.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just wondering.

Comment: You need keeps in blocks in the rows. Widows and orphans is a concept not about tables, but about paras and keeping lines together at together at the end of the page. If your input data is as you showed, then you need to parse through it and build separate block elements by understanding the break that is a blank line. Either that or fix the (ridiculous) input data by surrounding an object (a paragraph) with a tag.

Comment: To that, you have a template that is match="//description/p" ... where is a "p" tag in your input? I see ... uh ... none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input, you are probably out of luck unless the data is exactly as posed and you try some recursion to separate the data at a blank line. If your data was this (which surprising matches your XSL but you have no "p" element):

```
    <description>
        <p>row2 paragraph1 line1
        row2 paragraph1 line2
        row2 paragraph1 line3
        row2 paragraph1 line4
        row2 paragraph1 line5</p>
        <p>row2 paragraph2 line1
        row2 paragraph2 line2
        row2 paragraph2 line3
        row2 paragraph2 line4
        row2 paragraph2 line5
        row2 paragraph2 line6
        row2 paragraph2 line7</p>
    </description>
```

Then you could apply keeps at the "p" level to keep the content together. Because your input does not have that, you need to write a template that creates separate blocks and applies keeps on those blocks for the one text() node that is the child of the description element.

It would also need to preserve line breaks if that is also your intention.

OK, now if your data is truly as written (with line breaks and individual lines that you will live with in final output), then put each line into a table-row and use position to determine the few you wish to keep together.

Comment: I corrected my input data in an edit. I posted the wrong version of my xml-example. Sorry.
We tried to apply keep-together with blocks. Sadly those paragraphs can be bigger than a whole page. Content would then be cut off.

Comment: In revisiting this question. Is there some reason you are using a table for this? You are formatting this into tables and those tables only have one row. Why? For borders? Borders work on blocks too and you could just format into a block for the heading and a block for the remaining lines. Use a keep on the heading to keep it with the block following and then use widows and orphans.

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with me.
The "report" we are generating is rather complex. I took over this task from someone else, who I guess has a HTML-thinking in his way to layout this report: everything is a table in a table in a table and so on. I guess we will have to refactor the layouting to use blocks.

Comment: For now we used a programmatic way to generate different tags that indicate that a block should get the "keep-with-next" and/or "keep-together"-attributes during transformation. As this is a really dirty solution I will not post it here. Maybe someone should answer this question as "not possible to use orphans within tables"?
PS: I noticed the example is rather misleading. The first two tables are only copy-paste-replace-fillers so the third table would have the problem of a pagebreak within a row. Sorry again.

Comment: a table has no concept of widows or orphans for good reason. it would have many columns to worry about. as you rightly pointed out, you are using a table to layout wh should not be in a table. imagine the permutations a formatter would have to consider trying to autofit content into columns and consider 'widows or ophans' for a 10 column table. no more than 2 and no less than 3 for every column... no way.

Comment: Thanks. This confirms that I will have to refactor all templates used to create the reports.